# Sort rows of a 2d array by values in 3rd column in a descending direction

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

I have a 2d array with rows containing an id number, a name string, and the number of times the name occurs.

I would like to sort the array by count value in a descending order.

Sample array:

```
[
    [1, 'Al', 3],
    [2, 'Bea', 2],
    [3, 'Chan', 1], 
    [4, 'Doug', 2],
    [5, 'Ed', 3],
    [6, 'Fey', 1],
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    [1, 'Al', 3],
    [5, 'Ed', 3],
    [2, 'Bea', 2], 
    [4, 'Doug', 2],
    [3, 'Chan', 1],
    [6, 'Fey', 1],
]
```

`sort()` and `ksort()` don't do what I require.

Comment: I find the question confusing. Could you add an example with what the input data would look like, and what the end result should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [uasort()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to sort with a callback function. Example:

```
function sort_callback($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array1, 'sort_callback');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the way you've presented the question, but are you trying to do something like this?

```
function order_by($data, $field_name) {

    $code = "return strnatcmp(\$a['$field_name'], \$b['$field_name']);";
    usort($data, create_function('$a,$b', $code));
    return $data;

}
```

So, for example:

```
$array1 = array();
$array1[] = array('Id' => 1, 'Name' => 'YT', 'Count' => 30);
$array1[] = array('Id' => 2, 'Name' => 'Da5id', 'Count' => 56);
$array1[] = array('Id' => 3, 'Name' => 'Fido', 'Count' => 12);
$array1[] = array('Id' => 4, 'Name' => 'Hiro', 'Count' => 45);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
echo "</pre>";

$array2 = order_by($array1, 'Count');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array2);
echo "</pre>";
```